# How to redirect to static file?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a controller action that returns a static file:

```
public IActionResult GetPage([FromQuery] string form)
{
    var page = string.Concat(form, ".html");
    return File(Path.Combine("~/html/", page), "text/html");
}
```

A requested url might look like:

> https://myurl/api/controller?form=myform

And the file served, in this case "myform.html" has a link to another static file which is located in the same folder, eg:

```
<a href="secondform.html" target="_self">Another form</a>
```

The problem is that the link generated for the second file is:

> https://myurl/api/controller/secondform.html

Which obviously doesn't work.

How can I get this scenario to work? Do I need to use redirection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might help to change the link in `myform.html` to:

```
<a href="api/controller?form=secondform" target="_self">Another form</a>
```

If you don't have control over `myform.html` (can't change it), it is also possible to achieve similar result with routes. Somthing like:

```
[Route("api/controller/{form}")]
public IActionResult GetPage([FromQuery] string form)
{
    if (!form.Contains(".html"))
        var page = string.Concat(form, ".html");
    return File(Path.Combine("~/html/", page), "text/html");
}
```